# Creating Gmail draft after deployment not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, gmail-api

I am trying to create a Gmail draft using the the Gmail API.

When in development it works perfectly, but when I deploy it I get an error message.

```
POST http://myapp.appspot.com/emailDoc 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This is what my Flask route function looks like:

```
# Flask Route
@app.route('/emailDoc', methods=["POST"])
def emailDoc():

    # Get Oauth2 Credentials
    credentials = Credentials().get_by_id('tokens')
    if not authcheck(credentials):
        return 'error'

    # Create ReportLab PDF
    buff = StringIO()
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buff, pagesize=A4,
                          rightMargin=1.25*cm,leftMargin=1.25*cm,
                          topMargin=1.25*cm,bottomMargin=1.25*cm)
    doc.build(genpdf(data))

    # Create Email Message
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['to'] = to@email.com
    message['from'] = 'me'
    message['subject'] = 'Hello'

    messageBody = MIMEText("Hello Wolrd")

    messageFile = MIMEBase('application', 'pdf')
    messageFile.set_payload(str(buff.getvalue()))
    messageFile.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='document.pdf')

    message.attach(messageBody)
    message.attach(messageFile)

    # Oauth2 Flow
    access_token = credentials.access_token
    flow = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, 'myapp')
    http = flow.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    # HTTP Request
    obj = http.request(
        uri='https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts',
        method='POST',
        body={
          'message': {
            'raw':base64.urlsafe_b64encode( message.as_string() )
           }
        },
        headers={'content-type':'application/json'}
    )[1]

    return obj
```

This is the error message I get in the Google Developers Console Logging Tab.

```
Exception on /emailDoc [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/main.py", line 471, in emailDoc
    headers={'content-type':'application/json'}
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 589, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1593, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1335, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1291, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/gae_override/httplib.py", line 522, in getresponse
    **extra_kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~admin-app/1.388311669567787470/lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1091, in fixed_fetch
    validate_certificate=validate_certificate)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 270, in fetch
    allow_truncated, follow_redirects, validate_certificate)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 326, in make_fetch_call
    request.set_payload(payload)
  File "cpp_message.pyx", line 124, in cpp_message.SetScalarAccessors.Setter (third_party/apphosting/python/protobuf/proto1/cpp_message.cc:2229)
TypeError: <type 'dict'> has type <type 'dict'>, but expected one of: str, unicode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somewhere in your code you are sending a dictionary instead of a string.. I suggest that you use [gmail python library](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create), it's very fast forward, and they have code snaps for every call.

```
"""Generates and submits an email as a draft.
"""

import base64
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
import os

from apiclient import errors


def CreateDraft(service, user_id, message_body):
  """Create and insert a draft email. Print the returned draft's message and id.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message_body: The body of the email message, including headers.

  Returns:
    Draft object, including draft id and message meta data.
  """
  try:
    message = {'message': message_body}
    draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId=user_id, body=message).execute()

    print 'Draft id: %s\nDraft message: %s' % (draft['id'], draft['message'])

    return draft
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
    return None


def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64 encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}


def CreateMessageWithAttachment(sender, to, subject, message_text, file_dir,
                                filename):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: The email address of the sender.
    to: The email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.
    file_dir: The directory containing the file to be attached.
    filename: The name of the file to be attached.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64 encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEMultipart()
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject

  msg = MIMEText(message_text)
  message.attach(msg)

  path = os.path.join(file_dir, filename)
  content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(path)

  if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
    content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
  main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
  if main_type == 'text':
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  elif main_type == 'image':
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  elif main_type == 'audio':
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    fp.close()
  else:
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
    msg.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()

  msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
  message.attach(msg)

  return {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I ended up doing in the end.

Answer (score 1):

`http.request` requires `body=` to be a string. You must `json.dumps` your `dict` before passing it in.

```
# HTTP Request
obj = http.request(
    uri='https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts',
    method='POST',
    # json encoded string
    body=json.dumps({
      'message': {
        'raw':base64.urlsafe_b64encode( message.as_string() )
       }
    }),
    headers={'content-type':'application/json'}
)[1]
```